# Regarding Chat Application using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am a new in node.js and socket.io need help. Actually i have to create a chat application its a kind of Customer Support where admin section will be there and multiple user can chat with admin and resolve their query.
Currently i have build a simple chat application where multiple user can open the url open the chat box and can chat with other. Please let me know any resources or tips how to can i integrate admin panel and multiple user chat request.
Below is the code where i have created chat system for multiple users.

Server Side Code

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports= function(app, io){  

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.render('home');
    });


    // Initialize a new socket.io application, named 'chat'
    var chat = io.on('connection', function (socket){
        connections.push(socket);
        console.log("Connected: %s sockets connected", connections.length);

        socket.on('join',function(data){
            socket.join(data);
            rooms.push(data);
            console.log(rooms.length);
        });

        //Disconnect
        socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
            connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
            console.log("Disconnected: %s sockets connected", connections.length);
            rooms.pop();
            console.log(rooms.length);
        });

        socket.on('sendMsg',function(data){
            // console.log("this " +data.message);
            // console.log("this " +socket.username);
            if(rooms.length<=2){
                io.emit('newmsg',{msg:data.message,user:socket.username});
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('User Limit Reached');
            }
        });

        socket.on('login',function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            // callback(true);
            socket.username=data.user;
            users.push(socket.username);
            // console.log(users);
        });

    });

}
```

Client Side Code

```
 // $(function(){

  //connect to socket
  var socket=io();

  var id=12345;
  // on connection to server get the id of person's room
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected');
    socket.emit('join',id);
  });


// });

function sendMsg()
{
  var msg=$(".chat_input").val();

  // var name=sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
  socket.emit('sendMsg',{message:msg});
}

socket.on('newmsg',function(xyz){

  var tt='';

  var sessionUser=sessionStorage.getItem('userName');

  //For Date
  var currentTime = new Date(),
 hours =currentTime.getHours(),
 minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if(sessionUser==xyz.user)
  {
    tt='base_sent';
  }
  else
  {
    tt='base_receive';
  }


      chatHtml ='<div class="row msg_container '+tt+'"">';
      if(tt=='base_receive'){
      chatHtml += '<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar"></div>';}
      chatHtml +='<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 chatmsg">';
      chatHtml +='<div class="messages msg_sent">';
      chatHtml +='<b>'+xyz.user+'</b>';
      chatHtml +='<p>'+xyz.msg+'</p>';
      chatHtml +='<time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">'+hours+':'+minutes+'</time>';
      chatHtml +='</div>';
      chatHtml += '</div>';
      if(tt=='base_sent'){
      chatHtml += '<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar"></div>';}
      chatHtml += '</div>';
      chatHtml += '</div>';

    // $('.msg_container').last().after(chatHtml).fadeIn(1000);

    $('.msg_container_base').append(chatHtml);
    var msg=$(".chat_input").val('');
    sessionStorage.setItem('chatBody', chatHtml);
    $(".msg_container_base").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() },1000);
});
```

Comment: This question is too vague and broad for SO, sorry.

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks for your reply can you please give me little steps or hint so that i can proceed.

Comment: You could have a look at existing chat servers (such as [mine](https://github.com/Canop/miaou) for example) but the truth is this is a software you'll have to think, design and build yourselves. Only on specific technical points will SO be able to help.

Comment: @DenysSéguret ok will go through different example thanks